# Navigation Bar missing in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, debugging, uinavigationcontroller

I am very new to iPhone development, but I have been given an iPhone application to debug and I don't know where to start.

The problem is as follows:

The app has a view which has a navigation bar on top. When I press the home button on the device, the application goes to suspended mode I suppose. When I go back to the app from the list I can see the view but without navigation bar. Why would the navigation bar disappear, and how can I fix it?

Here is the code for the same

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    [self prepareNavBar];
}



-(void)prepareNavBar
{
     self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = NO;

    CustomNavBar *the_pNavBar = [[CustomNavBar alloc] init];
    [the_pNavBar prepareNavbarWithLeftButtonImage:nil leftButtonAction:nil titleImage:    [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]     stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ip4_heading_comments.png"]] rightButtonImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ip4_submit.png"]] rightAction:@selector(postComment) target:self backgroundImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ip4_background_grey_150px.png"]] navigationBar:self.navigationController.navigationBar isStandardNavBar:NO];
[the_pNavBar release];

}
```

please let me know if any other code is required

Comment: Would be much easier if you add some code.

Comment: Show the code for setting up the navigation controller and adding its root view controller.  Identify the file it's in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by the following code

```
-(void)didBecomeActive:(NSNotificationCenter *)in_pNotif
{
    [self performSelector:@selector(test) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.01];
}

-(void)test
{
    self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = YES;
}
```